# activate timer on first click of button

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I am creating a web page where the user clicks a button as many times as they can in 5 seconds. Currently the timer starts when the page is initially loaded. However, I would like the timer to start when the user **first** clicks the 'Click' button and is not reset every time the user clicks the button after the first click.

Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks in advance.

HTML button:

```
<div class='buttonDiv'>
        <button onclick='countClicks()' id='click' type="button">Click Me!</button>
    </div>
```

Javascript functions:

```
/*record clicks*/
var clicks = 0;

function countClicks(){
document.getElementById('click').value = ++clicks;
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = clicks;
}


/* Timer countdown */
var secs=5;
var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer(){
 secs--;
 if (secs <= 0){
 clearInterval(counter);
 document.getElementById("click").disabled = true;

 document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML=0;
 return;

 }
 document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML=secs;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply declare the counter variable then check if it is set inside the function:

```
var counter;

function countClicks(){

    if( !counter ){//counter is not set

        counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

    } else {

        document.getElementById('click').value = ++clicks;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = clicks;
    }
}
```